# VBA not inputting Excel formula

Tags: vba, excel

I've been stuck on this for the past couple of hours and it's driving me nuts. I'm trying to enter this formula in cell B2:

```
=IF(OR(C2="Yes",D2="Yes",E2="Yes",F2="Yes",G2="Yes",H2="Yes",I2="Yes"),"Yes",IF(AND(C2="No",D2="No",E2="No",F2="No",G2="No",H2="No",I2="No"),"No"))
```

The formula works fine but no formula is entered into the cell when run through a VBA macro.

I recorded the macro, copy-and-pasted the output, and the cell still remains blank. Here is the output from the recording:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(RC[1]=""Yes"",RC[2]=""Yes"",RC[3]=""Yes"",RC[4]=""Yes"",RC[5]=""Yes"",RC[6]=""Yes"",RC[7]=""Yes""),""Yes"",IF(AND(RC[1]=""No"",RC[2]=""No"",RC[3]=""No"",RC[4]=""No"",RC[5]=""No"",RC[6]=""No"",RC[7]=""No""),""No""))"
```

I've also tried Range("B2").Formula, without success.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: FYI your IF Statement is really long and you can eleminate the second part of your statement as the result would be the same  `=IF(OR(C2="Yes",D2="Yes",E2="Yes",F2="Yes",G2="Yes",H2="Yes",I2="Yes"),"Yes","No")` Only making your Formula smaller to make debugging easier. This is ofcourse unless you want to add another condition at the end after the last NO. So the formula reads if any of the cells are Yes then return a `Yes` else if ALL of the cells are NO then return a NO. (can be achieved with the shortened formula included in this comment)

Comment: When you say "The cell remains blank", do you mean that there is no formula in the cell after your code runs, or that the formula is there but it is evaluating to a (blank) value?

Comment: @izzymo Great, thanks for that tip. Just tried it and the output is the same!

Comment: @FreeMan There is no formula in the cell after the code runs. It works fine when input manually in Excel. I believe the problem lies in the syntax of the script. I'm thinking it has to do with the quotation marks.

Comment: Found the problem guys! It wasn't the formula/code. I was trying to move one cell to the left, go down to the last cell in the column containing a value, move to the right, select all the way up to the cell with the formula (B2), and fill down. Apparently it didn't `select` all the way up, it just moved there. B1 was empty so it filled that down. Should've debugged better. I was dead tired at the time. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Now that you have, you may want to consider trying to move your code away from `.select`, `Active*`, etc. It leads to too many issues like this. If you defined your range as `MyWksht.range("A1:B20")` that's much easier. Of course, you'll want to make the actual range dynamic, not hard coded, but it's easier in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the cells referenced are blank, you should be getting a 'FALSE' result.

Your if starts with
(OR(C2="Yes",D2="Yes",E2="Yes",F2="Yes",G2="Yes",H2="Yes",I2="Yes")
if any of these  = Yes then return a Yes

however, they are blank, so go on and do this bit 
IF(AND(C2="No",D2="No",E2="No",F2="No",G2="No",H2="No",I2="No"),"No")

they are still blank, and give FALSE - with the second if you are saying all the cells must be NO to give a NO return

can you post the data around the cell you are using?

Comment: The problem is not the formula itself (it runs fine in Excel) but the VBA code:

`Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(RC[1]=""Yes"",RC[2]=""Yes"",RC[3]=""Yes"",RC[4]=""Yes"",RC[5]=""Yes"",RC[6]=""Yes"",RC[7]=""Yes""),""Yes"",IF(AND(RC[1]=""No"",RC[2]=""No"",RC[3]=""No"",RC[4]=""No"",RC[5]=""No"",RC[6]=""No"",RC[7]=""No""),""No""))"`

For some reason, it doesn't get entered into the cells. Here is the data:

[link](http://s2.postimg.org/xt69yoel5/excelvba.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this formula - count how many are Yes and count how many are No.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$I$1,"Yes")>=1,"Yes",IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$I$1,"No")=7,"No"))
```

You still have the problem if there's a blank, or a value other than Yes or No.

If 5 say 'Yes' and 1 says 'Bob' it will return 'Yes', but if 6 says 'No' and 1 says 'Bob' it will return FALSE.

You need to say what happens if the second part isn't TRUE:

`=IF(OR(C2="Yes",D2="Yes",E2="Yes",F2="Yes",G2="Yes",H2="Yes",I2="Yes"),"Yes",IF(AND(C2="No",D2="No",E2="No",F2="No",G2="No",H2="No",I2="No"),"No",**"Neither Yes or No"**))`

or

`=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$I$1,"Yes")>=1,"Yes",IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$I$1,"No")=7,"No","**Neither Yes or No**"))`

or as @izzymo said - if at least one is Yes then return Yes, otherwise return No:

`=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$I$1,"Yes")>=1,"Yes","No")`

Comment: That's an interesting alternative method for the formula. I should've explained the problem better, however. The formula works fine when entered manually in Excel but nothing happens when run through a macro. So the shortened VBA code, per @izzymo, would be:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _`
  `"=IF(OR(RC[1]=""Yes"",RC[2]=""Yes"",RC[3]=""Yes"",RC[4]=""Yes"",RC[5]=""Yes"",RC[6]=""Yes"",RC[7]=""Yes""),""Yes"",""No""))"`

Answer (score 0):

An `IF` statement has 3 parts:

- the condition
- the "if true"
- the "if false".

Your first statement has all three:

- if (any of a bunch of cells is 'yes')
- 'Yes'
- another `IF` statement<sup>*</sup>

The problem is in "another `IF` statement", where you have:

- if (a bunch of cells are 'no')
- 'No'
- nothing...

`IF(AND(C2="No",D2="No",E2="No",F2="No",G2="No",H2="No",I2="No"),"No", ???put a false condition here???)`

<sup>* Or, you can do as `izzymo` suggested in the comment and replace "another `IF` statement" with "No", and end up with the same result</sup>

Comment: The third argument is optional.

Comment: That's interesting. I just looked up the MS docs, and you are correct, yet I've always received "There's an error with your formula" errors when I've left it out of Excel 2007 & 2010...

Comment: Possibly your error is from something else.  In Excel 2007, `=IF(FALSE,TRUE)` (no third argument) returns `FALSE`, as do more complex formulas that I've used frequently.